# 301 redirect specific URLs

Tags: htaccess, url, 301-redirect

I have a lot of 404 pages looks like that:

- `lalala/lalala/Users_PasswordReminder.aspx?something=lala`
- `lilili/lilili/Users_PasswordReminder.aspx`
- `/Users_PasswordReminder.aspx?username=admin`
- etc.

I want all of the URLs who have `Users_PasswordReminder.aspx` redirect to my main page of my domain.

how can I do that with *.htaccess*?

Comment: You might have a path relative link somewhere in your pages, which causes these links to be seen. You should check your code for <a href="Users_PasswordReminder.aspx"> code and replace it with correct path absolute URL, for example <a href="/Users_PasswordReminder.aspx">

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 Users_PasswordReminder\.aspx http://example.com
```